# Flight Booking to US

Tags: b1-b2-visas

Do I wait to get to the Point of Entry before I declare my interest to spend extra 3weeks on a conference visa or do I book my flight with allowance for the extra stay of 3 weeks.

Comment: You just book your tickets. B1/2 visas should normally be multiple-entry. Just explain to the immigration officer how long you would like to stay and (potentially) why you need to spend 3 weeks in the U.S.

Comment: @xuq01 I don't see anything in the question that suggests leaving and re-entering the US, in which case it does not matter whether the visa is valid for multiple entries.